# T-SQL get max value

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
    SELECT  P.ID, MAX(ENTERDATE) as ENTERDATE, MAX(B.CostID) as CostID 
    FROM Protocol P JOIN BANK B ON P.ID= B.ID                                   
    group by P.ID
```

I need to find out what the Maximum enterdate was along with the corresponding CostID but I do not want to use MAX(B.CostID) but I am forced
to do so as I have a group by P.ID and all other fields need to have some kind of aggregate. How do I say group by P.ID and show me the max(enterdate) but give me the corresponding CostID for that Enterdate?

Comment: can u post some sample data for both tables and ur desired o/p?

Comment: Is Enterdate from the Protocol table or the Bank table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT  P.ID, 
         ENTERDATE  = MAX(p.ENTERDATE), 
         CostID     = (SELECT CostID FROM Bank WHERE ID = p.ID)
  FROM  Protocol P                   
  group by P.ID
```

OR something like

```
SELECT  t.*,
        CostID
  FROM  Bank b
        JOIN (
                SELECT  P.ID, 
                         ENTERDATE  = MAX(p.ENTERDATE)
                   FROM  Protocol P                   
                   group by P.ID                
             ) t ON t.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: what does `ENTERDATE  = MAX(p.ENTERDATE)` do? mimer sql validator gave me T031, "BOOLEAN data type" warning - would it do the same as `MAX(p.ENTERDATE) AS  ENTERDATE`?

Comment: yes, its a way of Aliasing columns. You can replace it with `MAX(p.ENTERDATE) AS ENTERDATE`

Answer (score 1):

Why not subquery it:

```
SELECT MaxTable.*, BANK.CostID AS CostID  
FROM 
(
    SELECT  P.ID, MAX(ENTERDATE) AS ENTERDATE
    FROM Protocol P                                  
    GROUP BY P.ID
) AS MaxTable
JOIN BANK 
    ON MaxTable.ID = BANK.ID
```

Comment: why would you need to Join `Protocol` to `Bank` in the Inner Query (MaxTable)?

Comment: Oops, too much copy and paste :). Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the analytical function ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT p.id, p.enterdate, b.costid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY p.enterdate DESC) AS rownum
    FROM Protocol P JOIN BANK B ON P.ID= B.ID)
WHERE rownum = 1
```